# 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method loaderInfo action script error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, action

I am a newbie in flash. I want to test passing variables to swf file using flashvars, then I had been creating a action script file with name `"test_adver.as"`. I use this file in the fla file as class document. This is the code of `"test_adver.as"`:

```
package src{
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.display.LoaderInfo;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.text.TextField;

public class test_adver extends MovieClip {
    public function test_adver() {
        try {
            var param:Object=loaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;
        } catch (error:Error) {
            trace("Loading failed");
        }
    }
}
```

}

But when I run the code, the output displays `"1180: Call to a possibly undefined method loaderInfo action script error"`. I try debug an hours but cannot fix this issue. help me. Please! Sorry my English is not good.

Comment: thank you because help me fixed grammar error!

Comment: Slightly off topic, but in cases such as this, you should cast using the "as" keyword. If the object being cast inherits from the caster (or vice versa), you should use the as keyword. So... sprite as Shape. It's faster and easier on internal memory usage after the fact. If they do not inherit, you should then cast the way you did. So... Number(string).

Answer (score 0):

It should be a lot more simple. You are trying to request loaderInfo property, but for this you don't even need type casting.

```
var param:Object=this.root.loaderInfo.parameters;
```

Answer (score 0):

You did everything right except the below

```
var param:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;
```

Yes, there should be caps "L". It is enough to import LoaderInfo class for flashvars.